# Partition a graph into connected subgraphs of 3 vertices each

Tags: graphs, partitions

We need to partition a graph into subgraphs of 3 vertices each, such that every subgraph has at least 2 edges.

The problem is similar to the [partition into triangles problem](http://profs.sci.univr.it/%7Errizzi/classes/Complexity/provette/Mirko/pt_fine.pdf) (which is NP-complete) but not the same because each subgraphs may contain 2 or 3 edges (unlike the triangles problem, which requires 3 edges in each subgraph).

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be equivalently stated as follows:

*Can a graph be partitioned into vertex disjoint paths of lengths $3$*?

The problem is shown to be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard (see [Theorem 1 here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82153605.pdf)).

Note that the proof is given for $k$-partition problem. However, it holds for your problem as well. In the proof, the partitions must contain $3$ vertices; note the following statement written in the proof: "We claim that $S'$ can be partitioned into members of $C$ if and only if $G$ can be
partitioned into $p = p' + 3q'$ paths of length at most $3$.
Since $|V| = 3p$, if $G$ can be partitioned into $p$ paths of length at most $3$, then each of these paths must have exactly $3$ vertices on it."